# Merge with delete nested query not giving delete count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying merge with delete in that I want to take count of records getting deleted.

I have following snippet

```
MERGE @DuplicateCurrencyData DD 
USING (SELECT PP.PAYMENTB_ID,PP.PPID,PP.BID FROM ProfileTable PP) tempTable
            ON DD.PPID = tempTable.PPID

   WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET DD.PBID = tempTable.PAYMENTB_ID 

OUTPUT
    $action, Updated.PBID 'Updated' INTO #MergeCountP;
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 122
>   The multi-part identifier "Updated.PBID" could not be bound.

If I not take count `Merge` statement works fine. I am unable to understand how to get rid of it

Comment: The Updated.PBID always works?

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to get the newly updated id use `Inserted.ID` and if you want the old id use `deleted.id`.

```
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.PBID 'Updated' INTO #MergeCountP;
```